# Angular 8 router does not fire any events with `onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'` when trying to activate the same route

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Router config:

```
imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
      scrollPositionRestoration: 'top'
    })
  ],
```

My route:

```
  {
    path: 'orders',
    loadChildren: './modules/order/order.module#OrderModule',
    canLoad: [OrderGuard],
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'
  },
```

Then in my forchild:

```
 {
        path: 'new-order',
        component: NewOrderComponent,
        pathMatch: 'full',
        canActivate: [OrderGuard],
        runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'
      },
```

In my actual component:

```
 this.routerSubscription = this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      console.log('NAVIGATION EVENT', event);
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        console.log('NAVIGATION END');
        this.ngOnDestroy();
        this.initializeComponent();
      }
    });
```

No events whatsoever trigger after trying to re-activate the same route. Events do show up for the initial activation though.

EDIT: The guards do indeed get triggered.

EDIT: my ngOnDestroy code messing things up:

```
 if (this.routerSubscription) {
      this.routerSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need to call `ngOnDestroy`? I am sure that is the culprit. Can you share what in that method?

Comment: @Saksham it wasn't the ngOnDestroy per se, it was the fact that I was unsubscribing to the router events there, if you edit your answer I'll mark it as the solution and upvote it

Comment: I was thinking that only and I even changed my fiddle to unsubscribe to the router events right after my previous comment. updated the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately `onSameUrlNavigation` only executes guards and resolvers, and it does not reinitialize components.

A good part is that it does triggers navigation thus you have 2 approaches to follow

You can use the `Events` from the `RouterModule` to handle this as

```
constructor(private _router: Router) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this._router.events.subscribe(res => {
    if (res instanceof NavigationEnd) console.log("NavigationEnd Event");
  });
}
```

**OR**

You can pass a random number in the router navigation method and subscribe to that parameter to execute your logic

Stackblitz at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-route-reload

**Edit:**

As pointed out in my comment, it seems that there is something going on in the `ngOnDestroy` method and it seems like you might be unsubscribing to your route events subscription while calling `ngOnDestroy`. The fiddle is updated to show this scenario.

This would not only execute your routing events just once.

Comment: Thanks, not sure who/why is downvoting you now but I marked it as the solution and upvoted and that barely got it to 0